# I get error when i run (vim-cmd vmsvc/) in Esxi shell

Tags: vsphere, esxi, vmware-server

I get an error when I run this command:

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/devices.createnic 1 e1000e
```

The error is:

> Could not find matching network id or type

Comment: The command runs in Esxi 6.5  shell and in /usr/bin Directory

Answer (score 1):

You must specify a port group as a 3rd parameter, i.e. something like this

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/devices.createnic 1 e1000e "VM Network"
```

Port group is usually created on a standard or distributed switch.